# How to code Java Swing menu list?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenu, jmenuitem

I'm writing a basic notepad application on Swing. I have a Java Swing Menu. It's basically a `JMenuBar` with `JMenus` in it. One of the menus is a "Format"-menu with a "Font size" menu inside it(See image). The "font size" menu is supposed to have a list of numbers where I can choose the font size. But I can't seem to find a good solution for this.

I've tried using `JComboBox` and `JList`, but I need the GUI looking like it does in the image. In other words, it can't be a collapsed-dropdown menu, nor can it be in it's own window. Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can do this?

EDIT:
Important to take notice of is that I need the values sent to an `ActionListener`. What you see in the image are just normal `JMenuItems`. But for me to send the int-values of each `JMenuItem` to an `ActionListener` I would need 3 different `ActionListeners`. And they would need to be hard coded.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). It has a working example that will show you how to create sub menus.

> But for me to send the int-values of each JMenuItem to an ActionListener I would need 3 different ActionListeners. And they would need to be hardcoded.

Yes, that is the way is should be done. You should have 3 separate Actions. Each Action should have a value to specify the font size.

You can also read [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example of a simple editor that uses the default editor kit Actions to do the customization of the text.

The tutorial is a good place to start for all Swing basics.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop to add the different font sizes to the Font menu, and you can add the same `ActionListener` to all of the items in the Font menu. When the `ActionListener` is called, you can get the font size by getting the text of the event's source.

Here is an example how to do it. This example adds all even font sizes from 8 to 24 as seen in the picture:

[image]

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
ActionListener fontChangedListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int fontSize = Integer.valueOf(( (JMenuItem) e.getSource()).getText());
        System.out.println(fontSize);
    }
};

JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();

JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("Format");
mb.add(formatMenu);

JMenu fontMenu = new JMenu("Font");
formatMenu.add(fontMenu);

for ( int i = 8; i <= 24; i += 2 ) {
    JMenuItem sizeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("" + i);
    sizeMenuItem.addActionListener(fontChangedListener);
    fontMenu.add(sizeMenuItem);
}

f.setJMenuBar( mb );
```